# calling PCACompute method is OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently working on code converting problem. The original code is in Python, and I want to convert it to C++. The Python code use the function cv2.PCACompute(). I want to know how to call that function in C++. More specifically, what is the type of the input that I need to pass to the cv::PCACompute function. I read the api reference (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4e2073c7311f292a0648f04c37b73781) but still could not figure out what exactly is the data I need to pass in. And I could not find any example.
If anyone could tell me or give me an example using the function in c++, what would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv::PCACompute` is a wrapper over `PCA::operator ()`: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cv2.pcacompute#pca-operator

There is a [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html) showing how to do PCA with opencv, but it doesn't use `PCACompute`.

Looking at the code, note the lines

```
//Perform PCA analysis
PCA pca_analysis(data_pts, Mat(), PCA::DATA_AS_ROW);
```

The first two parameters are similar to `cv::PCACompute`. The first one is the data matrix. The second one is the mean of the data. If it's empty, as here, the function will compute the mean itself. Otherwise, it will use the provided mean.

`cv::PCACompute` also takes 2 arrays as parameters, that will be populated with the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, respectively. The last parameter is optional, and can be used to keep a number of maximal components.

There is still the issue of the data layout, which is specified explicitly in `PCA::operator()` but here there is no way of indicating it. Looking at the actual code for `cv::PCACompute`, which can be found [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/pca.cpp#L352-L361), it passes the value 0 to `PCA::operator()` to indicate the data layout. Looking at that enum [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/d8d/classcv_1_1PCA.html), 0 mean `DATA_AS_ROW`, which is consistent with the tutorial example.